# Поиск цели распознавания

Tags: opencv, нейронные-сети, распознавание-образов

На пример нужно распознавать номера автомобиля, или другие буквенные/цифровые значения на каком-нибудь изображении, для этого используется нейронная сеть. Но для начала же нужно найти где именно на изображении находится номер автомобиля, а потом уже передавать эту часть на сетку. Как можно реализовать именно эту часть с поиском нужны данных для передачи нейронной сети? Знаю, что для подобных целей широко используется OpenCV, но подходит ли она именно для этой задачи? Или есть другие более подходящие решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Уважаемая Арина, прошу извинения за "флейм", но по моему на данной площадке мало людей, разбирающихся в OpenCv. Знаете ли Вы какие-нибудь другие форумы (в первую очередь русскоязычные), где обитают специалисты по OpenCV ?